# With help of Application.InputBox() method let user to select multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, select, range, inputbox

I have a code in `VBA`, where with help of `inputBox method` user is able to select a `cell`, `a range`. But I need to have an inputBox where user is able to select multiple cell ranges, ( not with help of `Selection` method!!) then to split each cell value.

code is below

```
Set Group = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a cell to be expanded", Left:=100, Type:=8)

Dim str_group As String

Debug.Print Split(str_group, ":")(0)
```

`type:=8` give ability to select only a cell, [Mcrst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox)even if user selects multiple cells, it only reads first cell range(address) I need to see after `:` and to be able to read it.

Comment: `Application.InputBox` with its `Type` argument's parameter set to `8` captures the selected range even if it is discontinuous no matter what you say. Could you share what you are trying to accomplish by sharing a scenario using real values e.g. if I select cells `A1` and `C2` I want their contents split by a colon returned in an array i.e. if `A1` contains `dog:cat` and `C2` `wolf:Leppard`, I need an array with these 4 words, or I want to return them in column A of `Sheet2` starting with A2... Maybe a screenshot of your data would help. Also, what does *"Select a cell to be expanded"* mean?

Comment: I shared a picture but do not know, if it is helpful or not? I bypassed the situation by taking `Address` of input value then splitting it up

Comment: Dealing with cell addresses is a horrible idea and will give you only headaches. `Group` is a range containing all those cells. To loop through them, use e.g. `Dim cell As Range: For Each cell in Group.Cells: Debug.Print cell.Address, cell.Value: Next cell` (where each colon denotes a new line), and in the Immediate window (`Ctrl+G`) see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this article by Microsoft official website.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox
```

In my case the below code worked just fine.

```
Sub test()
    Dim myRange As Variant
    Set myRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a cell to be expanded", Type:=8)
    Debug.Print myRange.Address
End Sub
```

Debug output was `$A$4:$C$11` as I selected those cells. Hope this is helpful ...